# The figure always has a line when I use basemap toolkit in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

The figure shows that there is one line across the America.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
map = Basemap(projection='ortho', 
          lat_0=0, lon_0=0,resolution='l') 
map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()
x, y = map(0, 0)
map.plot(x, y, marker='D',color='m')
plt.show()
```

Comment: where is figure ?..atleast link the figure

Comment: You could upload your figure to an online place (e.g., Google Drive https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive) and post its URL (until your reputation is elevated).